# How to measure time for Python programs that crash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, assert, timeit

I want to accurately measure time of a Python code, that crashes. I can use the `time` command for unix, but that isn't as precise as `time.time` module in Python

```
start = time.time()
assert(1 < 0)
print(time.time() - start)
```

The code -- above -- definitely doesn't work if executed as Python code (although inside a Python interpreter it works, but that isn't desirable) , I am asking if there is a work-around ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a custom [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) function which will be called right before your program "crashes":

```
start = time.time()

def my_excepthook(type, value, traceback):
    end = time.time()
    print("Program crashed after", end - start, "seconds")
    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, traceback)  # Print error message

sys.excepthook = my_excepthook
```

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate this in my Python itself (I am in a virtual environment) ?
Great solution!

Comment: @Sahil It's complicated... You better should put this code in a small module file like `crashtime.py` and import it anytime you want to measure the crash time by adding `import crashtime` at the start of your script.

Comment: How would the variable `start` be defined in that case ?

Comment: @Sahil the sam way: just add it at the start of `crashtime.py` and call `import crashtime` at the very start of your program.

Answer (score 0):

you can use try except:

```
start = time.time()
try:
    assert(1 < 0)
except:
    print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: This can be done, but say I want to do this for assertion errors inside TensorFlow which has tonnes of Assertions errors spread over exotic file locations.

Comment: you can include all the code in a try except if is fine with you

Comment: especially if you import form another module is more simple, you can take into consideration the case  of a crash and do something